# Is there a way to obtain a pointer to QScrollBar context menu?

Tags: qt, qt5, qscrollarea

I want to reimplement contextmenuevent method for `QScrollbar` in Qt 5.6, with minimal changes in functionality. This can be done if I obtain a pointer to the `QScrollBar` context menu. However, there seems to be no method to obtain the original `QScrollbar` context menu. Another option can be to create a `QMenu` and add the actions associated with each item in the new menu. For example, I can add the 'Scroll Here' item, and attach the action associated with Scroll Bar context menu, if I know the method which is called when I click on 'Scroll Here' in the original context menu. Is there a way to obtain these actions?

Answer (score 0):

The menu is generated each time there is a context menu event. The [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qscrollbar.cpp) will show you how to construct an identical menu. It's fairly short and very straightforward:

```
QPointer<QMenu> menu = new QMenu(this);
QAction *actScrollHere = menu->addAction(tr("Scroll here"));
...
QAction *actionSelected = menu->exec(event->globalPos());
delete menu;

if (actionSelected == 0)
    /* do nothing */ ;
else if (actionSelected == actScrollHere)
    setValue(d_func()->pixelPosToRangeValue(horiz ? event->pos().x() : event->pos().y()));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CustomContextMenuPolicy:

```
  QScrollBar *scroll = new QScrollBar;
  scroll->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
  connect(scroll, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(populateContextMenu(QPoint)));
```

And in the slot populateContextMenu():

```
QMenu* menu = new QMenu;
// Add actions
QAction* example = menu->addAction("Example");
// Connect the action clicked with the slot 
connect(example, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),.....);
// Finally, show the context menu, map to global to show the correct position
const QPoint pos = ui->listView->mapToGlobal(point);
menu->popup(pos);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [triggerAction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qabstractslider.html#triggerAction) and [setValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qabstractslider.html#value-prop) for your new context menu.

Comment: This does not answer the question.